Answers that didn't answer the question
If the moon was covered in blood, would it achieve the visual effect of deep red moonlight under a full moon?
This question specifically asked for "can a bloodied moon cast red moonlight on earth", not "can a bloodied moon be seen as red". To be fair, this clarification was edited in after someone answer the question. I feel that the answerers misunderstood the initial question, thus the clarification was not changing the question.
With/without this edit, some current answers didn't address the actual question asked.
What to do with this question?
The answers are, at least one, high quality, but answer the wrong question. Upvotes are coming because it's high quality.
Should we just leave comments on each answer asking to update on "is this enough to cast red moonlight on earth" or leave an official notice?

Where has the "edits shall not invalidate existing answers" principle gone?

@L.Dutch actually, the question has not changed. The edit merely clarify what the asked actually asking. Answerers misunderstood the actual question. So, the edit is not wrong. I'm currently asking what to do with answers that misunderstood the initial question - should we just downvote and move on, delete them, just comment, or leave a note asking answerer to update their answer.

I thought that my answer covered this point... in effect, saying "Yes, but...".
If someone believes that points of an answer needs to be made clearer, that's what comments are for.
Sometimes, when posting comments, they need to come straight to the point and say "Could you please make X clearer."  What's obvious to some isn't necessarily obvious to all.

Maybe my command of English is not that high, but I don't see a difference between the two points added in the edit. In both cases the light sent back from the Moon surface is red, but in one case is hitting directly the observer's eyes, in the other it's first bouncing on another surface.
How does this make the existing answers wrong?

After thinking about this, I agree that it actually might be the same. However what I thought when I read the edit is that the OP want anime-ish dramatic effect of red moonlight when the moon appears. I never thought that gazing upon the moon and see it as red = bathed in red moonlight. Now I wonder if both are the same or different

This was an educational experience
@Sphennings and I reviewed this question in the Sandbox and after a few minor changes we both thought it was ready to go. We both read the question in the same way, based (in hindsight) on the wording of the title. We knew Dmyt was looking for whether or not the moonlight would cast the Earth in a red light.
Technically, that is the same as "would the moon look red when I look at it?" Kinda. The light reflected from the moon is red. If it's strong enough, it would cast red light onto the Earth. But while they're technically the same thing, they're not actually the same. The difference is quantity. It takes a whole lot less reflected red light to see the moon as red than it does to see my sidewalk under a full moon as red.
Were answers invalidated?
@L.Dutch is correct that the Stack has a policy of not modifying questions to invalidate answers. I'm to blame, because I felt the question was clear coming out of the Sandbox. It proved not to be, so I edited the question (the edit was blessed by Dmyt) to clarify the goal.
The policy is still in effect and I intentionally violated it. But @Vylix is also correct. The clarification did not change the original intent of the question and @L.Dutch is correct in that because we're talking about the same basic physical phenomena, none of the answers were technically invalidated.
What this really means is that this question got honking lucky. It's a one-off that cannot and should not be used in any argument pro or con relating to the edits-vs-answers policy.
So, what did you learn?

Short questions are a bad thing. Sandbox mentors should encourage Sandbox participants to be reasonably verbose.

Don't trust the belief that what I think is clear means it's clear to everyone (I've actually preached this in comments and Meta posts... you'd think I'd remember).

More people should mentor in the Sandbox.


And what should we do about the question?
Not a darn thing. If this was the worst thing to happen to us in this last week, we're in great shape and blessed beyond measure. So long as Dmyt received the insight he/she required, it's not worth doing anything about the question. It will slowly fade into the miasma of archived questions like all others and we'll all be unlikely to remember it a month from now.
